# Moving website from localhost to existing website without altering existing live theme

Tags: themes, import, localhost, export

Current situation :

- I have wordpress website called publishingnext.in which is hosted on one.com
- I have built  another complete website on localhost called **conference**.

What i want guidance for:

- I want to move the entire website(conference) from localhost to live along with the content, without affecting the existing live content.
- I want help on exporting/importing content and database from localhost to live.

Reason for moving :

- I will be switching from  the existing theme from (Theme:Heuman) to the the one on localhost(Theme:talkingbusiness_lite) **eventually**.

Alternate solution that i had :

- Install the (Theme:talkingbusiness_lite) on live and then import the demo content data(Query:Will it replace/break the existing content? )
- (Note : It uses Cherry Data Importer)

I have fair knwoledge of Wordpress as i am a beginner.Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 :
Since I wanted fresh setup without going through the hassle of changing urls in the database, I went ahead and imported the data from theme and further made the changes on my own.

Option 2 :
If you really want your old content then I would suggest to use the export option given by the Wordpress wherein we can export almost all aspects like comments,posts,pages and so on.But on the new website we have to install Wordpress Importer plugin.For more on this method, read this article [Migrating Old Wordpress Content to New Domain](http://blog.cinnamonteal.in/wordpress-guide-migrating-website-content/)